# Is there anyway of keeping the formatting of source code while copying to TeXstudio?

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

Like the title says, TeXstudio deletes all white spaces (except new lines) when pasting source code from any editor to it (in my case vscode (win 10)). Is there any way to keep the indents?

nvm. Edited the file externally (indents were reloaded).

Comment: Not a perfect solution but when copying large segments between files, I always comment them first, copy, paste, and uncomment them again in both files.

Comment: I'll try it next